# best design practice to separate common code?

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a card class:

```
function Card()  {
    this.image = new Image();
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 400;

    this.initialX = 0;
    this.initialY = 0;

    this.scaleFactor = 4;

    this.setImage = function(ii){            
        this.image.src = ii;            
    };

    this.getWidth = function(){        
        if (this.image == null){
            return 0;
        }            
        return this.image.width / this.scaleFactor;        
    }

    this.getHeight = function(){                
        if (this.image == null){
            return 0;
        }            
        return this.image.height / this.scaleFactor;        
    }        

    this.pointIsInCard = function(mx, my){            
        if (mx >= this.x && mx <= (this.x + this.getWidth()) && my >= this.y && my <= (this.y + this.getHeight()))
        {                
            return true;                        
        }
        else{                
            return false;
        }            
    };        
};
```

I then have a deck class:

```
function Deck(x, y, w, h){    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;        

    this.cards = [];        
}
```

I need to add a method in `Deck` class similar to `pointIsInCard` instead it will be called `pointIsInDeck`. The logic will be same i.e to check whether the passed in point falls in the boundary of the object. So seeing this duplication of code I wanted to know what is a good design practice to avoid this duplication? One option I thought of was to extract the method out and create a function for generic object with `x`, `y`, `width`, `height` but again from OOP principles I thought this method should belong to the class/object. I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Have Helper class where you pass object to search in, point coordinates, w and h.

Comment: Are parameters same for each function?

Comment: Or have a super/ancestor of both Deck and Card that has the method.

Comment: @guest271314 yes the function is identical the only difference is the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common approach for what you're doing is to attach a `Rectangle` or similar instance with that functionality to both of your objects, that is:

```
class Rectangle {
    constructor(x, y, width, height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    containsPoint(x, y) {
        return x >= this.x && x =< this.width &&
            y >= this.y && y =< this.height;
    }
}
```

Then just add it to `Card` and `Deck`:

```
function Card() {
    this.rect = new Rectangle(/* Your card shape */);

    // ...
}

function Deck() {
    this.rect = new Rectangle(/* Your deck shape */);

    // ...
}
```

And you can do:

```
card.rect.containsPoint();
deck.rect.containsPoint();
```

Comment: ok i like this approach. I like composition over inheritance. I think i will go with this approach.

Comment: maybe instead of this.rect i can name it boundary which in my view is more descriptive. what do you think?

Comment: @user734861 Thinking about it, I believe bounds is actually a more common name :-)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I realized that in the above example you provided you have used class construct but i think that was added later in 2015. I am using function based object creation methods. What is your suggestion about using class over function. The only thing i am worried about is since it is a card game, the advantages of using the old approach could be it could be used by old browsers. The newer versions couldn't be available in all browsers. Please give some suggestions.

Comment: @user734861 My suggestion is to implement Babel in your workflow for future projects to get the best of both worlds (newer features and browser support).

Answer (score 1):

If these are classes related to drawing, they would both inherit from something like `Rectangle`, which they would both inherit this behaviour from.

If they are gameplay-related, I would prefer them each referencing a `Rectangle` (or its subclass) that they would delegate all UI-related tasks to; then reduce this to the previous paragraph's solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Function.prototype.call()` to set `this` at a function call

```
function Card()  {
  this.x = 1; this.y = 2;
};

function Deck() {
  this.x = 10; this.y = 20;
}

function points(x, y) {
  // do stuff
  console.log(x, this.x, y, this.y); // `this`: `c` or `d`
}

var c = new Card();

var d = new Deck();

points.call(c, 3, 4); // `this`: `c` within `points` call

points.call(d, 100, 200); // `this`: `d` within `points` call
```